# Audio recording using AudioRecord class and playback using AudioTrack class

Tags: android, audio-recording, audiotrack

Hi I have been tried to record audio through MIC using AudioRecord class and store it in the buffer of size 2048.

And I tried to playback the recorded audio from that buffer itself using AudioTrack class creating another buffer of same size. When I Run the Application, it displays my main.xml file and it shows "Unfortunately app has stopped". It does not record anything too itseems. I just want to play audio from the recording buffer itself. Can anyone help me out? This is my code.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

class AudRecord
{
    public AudioRecord recorder; 
    public boolean isRecording;
    public int SAMPLERATE;
    public int CHANNELS;
    public int AUDIO_FORMAT;
    public int buffer; 
    public Thread recordingThread;

    public AudRecord()
    {
        recorder = null;
        isRecording = false;
        SAMPLERATE = 44100;
        CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
        AUDIO_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        recordingThread = null;
        buffer = 2048;
    }
    public void StartRecording() {


        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLERATE,
                CHANNELS, AUDIO_FORMAT, buffer);

        recorder.startRecording();
        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable()

        {
            public void run() {
                writeAudioData();
            }

        });
        recordingThread.start();

    }



     void writeAudioData() {


        byte data[] = new byte[2048];

        while (isRecording) {

            recorder.read(data, 0, buffer);
            send(data);

        }
    }

    public void send(byte[] data) {

        int buffers = 2048;
        AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffers,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        at.play();
        at.write(data, 0, buffers);
        at.stop();
        at.release();

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AudRecord rec= new AudRecord();
    rec.StartRecording();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately app has stopped**  this means your XML file has problem.

`AudioRecording` Example using `MediaRecorder`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        start();
    }
    });
 ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stop();
    }
    });
    }
    public void start()
    {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"yourfilename.3gpp");
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have anything in my xml file except a blank file. I used a blank xml file as i want to record and playback audio as soon as i open my app.

Comment: @Yogesh Lakhotia Please use comments for this kind of responses.

Comment: i chked ur code its showing AudioRecorder is not initialized.
I have not worked with AudioRecorder class..but you can use MediaRecorder [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) its less complex than AudioRecorder